# Color stripes on screen

Tags: display

I’m typing from phone, ‘cause I can’t type any more on my computer. I have problems with my laptop screen. After turning on my computer I see **stripes on screen different colors like wallpaper**. They appear when I change  the angle position of screen. My guaranty was over 2 month ago, so, I don’t know what to do.
I really need working computer for my designers’ job as soon as possible.

Comment: Time for a new laptop?

Comment: Or to tear it apart and check the connections to any ribbon cables.  Check first by resetting the computer by removing all power inc. battery , wait for some time and be sure it is cooled down, and turn it back on again, in the case that any overheat fails (of that type) would reset. If it was overheating, then tear it apart and clean out the dust.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

can you tell what’s the model of your computer? I suppose you have to **fix stencil cable**.

Comment: Forgot about it Acer 572g-56pc

Comment: You can go to computer service or fix it by yourself, you can buy it.
Then you have to disassemble screen frame(because stencil cable is located in hinge that connects keyboard and screen of your laptop) and change the cable. Good luck with your repairing!

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have to find this part of my laptop.:) Thanks for all answers!